# GeoServer vector tiles TMS service how to set buffer parameter?

Tags: geoserver, tile-map-service

First, I use rest service to publish multi layers.So I want to find a place to set `Default Rendering Buffer` parameter or use the rest to set this buffer parameter. That I needn't set every layer one by one.

Second, I had found that use WMS service can set `buffer` parameter by set an explicit buffer parameter,So I want to know can set this parameter when I use TMS service? And I found that use `buffer=<bufferwidth>` like this can't work well: `http://host/geoserver/gwc/service/tms/1.0.0/layer@EPSG:900913@pbf/{z}/{x}/{y}.pbf?buffer=100`.

Even tried WMTS like this doesn't work too:`http://host/geoserver/gwc/service/wmts?REQUEST=GetTile&SERVICE=WMTS&VERSION=1.0.0&LAYER=layer&STYLE=&TILEMATRIX=EPSG:900913:{z}&TILEMATRIXSET=EPSG:900913&FORMAT=application/vnd.mapbox-vector-tile&TILECOL={x}&TILEROW={y}&VENDORPARAMS=buffer:100`

So what I need is somewhere to set this buffer parameter or some methods to set this buffer parameter when I use TMS/WMTS to loading vt layer.

Comment: &vendoparams? It should have been &buffer=100, and you need to make "buffer" a parameter filter in the layer configuration.

Answer (score 0):

The default value is set on the WMS settings section of the layer page, as described in the [manual](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/webadmin/layers.html#wms-settings). This can be overridden using an explicit `buffer` parameter in your getMap request as discussed in the [manual](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/services/wms/vendor.html#buffer).

Comment: Thanks! Now I use rest service to publish multi layers,So I want to find a place to set once or use the rest to set this buffer parameter.I'm using `TMS` to loading the layers which published by rest.And I found that use `buffer=<bufferwidth>` like this can't work:`http://host/geoserver/gwc/service/tms/1.0.0/layer@EPSG:900913@pbf/{z}/{x}/{y}.pbf?buffer=100`

Comment: I find GeoServer doc said add `-Dorg.geoserver.wms.featureinfo.minBuffer=10` to system variable,But this doesn't work for me.

Comment: please edit your question if there is information you need to make it clearer